Referencing the ID of a resouce created in other bicep files when a parent main.bicep is also used
How do I reference a resource created in a bicep file that shares the same parent main.bicep file?
I have three bicep files...
main.bicep
module ddosProtectionPlanModule 'ddosProtectionPlan.bicep' = {
  name: 'de-ddos-qa-01'
  scope: resourceGroup('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000','QA-01')
  params: {
    name: 'ddos-qa-01'
  }
}

module vnet 'vnet.bicep' = {
  name: 'VNet-dev-01'
  params: {
    ddosProtectionPlan: ddosProtectionPlanModule.outputs.ddosProtectionPlan
  }
}


ddosprotectionplan.bicep
param name string

resource ddosProtectionPlan 'Microsoft.Network/ddosProtectionPlans@2021-05-01' = {
  name: name
  location: resourceGroup().location  
}

output ddosProtectionPlan object = ddosProtectionPlan

vnet.bicep
param appTitle string = 'test'
param environment string = 'Dev'
param ddosProtectionPlan object

param vlanName string = '${appTitle}-vlan-${environment}-99'
param location string = resourceGroup().location

resource virtualNetwork 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2023-11-01' = {
  name: vlanName
  location: location
  properties: {
    addressSpace: {
      addressPrefixes: [
        '10.70.0.0/24'
      ]
    }
    enableDdosProtection: true
    ddosProtectionPlan: {
      id: ddosProtectionPlan.id
    }
  }
}

resource subnet_01 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets@2023-11-01' = {
  parent: virtualNetwork
  name: 'default'
  properties: {
    addressPrefixes: [
      '10.70.0.0/24'
    ]
    serviceEndpoints: [
      {
        service: 'Microsoft.Storage'
      }
      {
        service: 'Microsoft.Sql'
      }
    ]
  }
}

output virtualNetworkObject object = virtualNetwork


However when I run the main.bicep, I get the following error in Azure...

The language expression property 'id' doesn't exist, available properties are 'apiVersion, location, properties, condition, isConditionTrue, subscriptionId, resourceGroupName, scope, resourceId, referenceApiVersion, existing, isTemplateResource, isAction, isExtensibleResourceReference, provisioningOperation'.


Does below works? not tried at my side
main.bicep
module ddosProtectionPlanModule 'ddosProtectionPlan.bicep' = {
  name: 'de-ddos-qa-01'
  scope: resourceGroup('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000','QA-01')
  params: {
    name: 'ddos-qa-01'
  }
}

module vnet 'vnet.bicep' = {
  name: 'VNet-dev-01'
  params: {
    ddosProtectionPlanId: ddosProtectionPlanModule.outputs.ddosProtectionPlanId
  }
}


vnet.bicep
param appTitle string = 'test'
param environment string = 'Dev'

param ddosProtectionPlanId string

param vlanName string = '${appTitle}-vlan-${environment}-99'
param location string = resourceGroup().location

resource virtualNetwork 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2023-11-01' = {
  name: vlanName
  location: location
  properties: {
    addressSpace: {
      addressPrefixes: [
        '10.70.0.0/24'
      ]
    }
    enableDdosProtection: true
    ddosProtectionPlan: {
      id: ddosProtectionPlanId
    }
  }
}

resource subnet_01 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets@2023-11-01' = {
  parent: virtualNetwork
  name: 'default'
  properties: {
    addressPrefixes: [
      '10.70.0.0/24'
    ]
    serviceEndpoints: [
      {
        service: 'Microsoft.Storage'
      }
      {
        service: 'Microsoft.Sql'
      }
    ]
  }
}

output virtualNetworkObject object = virtualNetwork


ddosProtectionPlan.bicep
param name string

resource ddosProtectionPlan 'Microsoft.Network/ddosProtectionPlans@2021-05-01' = {
  name: name
  location: resourceGroup().location  
}

output ddosProtectionPlanId string = ddosProtectionPlan.id



That worked! I thought I did this in my initial testing but there might be something you did differently. Thanks for the help!
